# Cannot Find Stylesheet From Custom Library in Angular

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I'm using Angular v17. I'm building a custom library with a stylesheet that I'd like to import using `@import "@my-company/ngx-luai/styles/index";` in my application's `style.scss` file.

My compiled and imported library (as seen from my Application) shows the stylesheet in the correct location:

[image: Screenshot of imported package folder structure]

The Library's folder structure is:

[image: Screenshot of library's folder structure]

The Library's `ng-package.json` has the assets directory declared:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "input": "src/lib/resources/styles",
    "glob": "**/*.scss",
    "output": "styles"
  }
]
```

And the Library's `package.json` has the following export declared:

```
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "sass": "./styles/_index.scss"
  }
},
```

However, when I go to compile my Application, I get the following error:

```
./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-e
xtract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):        
Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
3 │ @import "@my-company/ngx-luai/styles/index";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\styles.scss 3:9  root stylesheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you have configured in the `package.json`'s exports, you need to import the styles from the following path:

```scss
 @import "@my-company/ngx-luai";
```

You can read more about package exports in the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/).